# the meaning of 'acquired by'

Tags: meaning, word-usage

What is the meaning of 'acquired by' ?  Can I use this phrase in what scene?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merriam Webster gives two definitions of the word **acquired:**

> gained by or as a result of effort or experience

and

> attained as a new or added characteristic, trait, or ability

Link: [Acquired definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acquired)

So what **acquired by** means is when something is attained or obtained by someone (it can be an individual or a company)

*Example*:

1. Company A was *acquired by* company B.
2. They have access to private information that can only be acquired by those who invest millions of dollars in network communication.

Answer (score 0):

Given the definition "gain an asset or ability" for acquire, common examples are

> Startup is acquired by company
>   Knowledge is acqired by student

here **by "someone"** tells us who has gained / acquired something.

> Fortune was acquired by illegal operations

now **by "something"** explains how the acquisition was performed.